# multiprocessing not executing any class function - python2.7.13

Tags: python, class, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use `multiprocessing.Pool` to run class functions asynchronously. But it seems as if I can't call any class functions inside `pool.apply_async()`. Functions defined in the same file are fine though.

Is this known behavior and I missed it and if yes, what could I do to run my functions asynchronously with the least amount of code possible ?

These are my two files demonstrating the issue:

```
## test.py ##
import multiprocessing as mp
from testclass import testclass

def nonclass_test():
    print("nonclass_test")

def nonclass_callback(self):
    print("nonclass_callback")


pool = mp.Pool()

test = testclass()

#test.test()
#print("testclass working ...")

#pool.apply_async(nonclass_test, args = (), callback = nonclass_callback)
pool.apply_async(test.test, args = (), callback = nonclass_callback)
pool.apply_async(test.test, args = (test, ), callback = test.callback)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

--

```
## testclass.py ##
class testclass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("initiated")

    def test(self):
        print("classtest")

    def callback(self):
        print("classcallback")
```

In my output, I only get the messages `"nonclass_test"` and `"nonclass_callback"`. It seems as if the class functions (neither callback, nor actual function) are being executed.

Thanks for your help already.

Comment: `args = (test,)` maybe you have to provide the actual instance as an argument?

Comment: @jbndlr also not working :/

Comment: That's interesting. I just tested it on Linux and for Python 2 the only output I get is `initiated`, while for Python 3 I get `initiated`, `classtest` and `nontest_callback`... I think the Python 3 output is correct, but the second call is failing because it has an extra argument (I just checked that passing an `error_callback`, which unfortunately is not an available parameter in Python 2).

Comment: Mh ok, thought about going for Python3 already, but then I could simply use `asyncio`, so I tried it with `multiprocessing` ...